# Running two nodes for two webcams with usb_cam

Tags: ros, camera, rosrun, usb-cam, usb-cam-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run two different webcams. What I understood was I need to create two different nodes and set the parameters differently to run them. Both are [Logitech C270 cameras](http://www.logitech.com/en-in/product/hd-webcam-c270).

What I did was copy the usb_cam_node.cpp file to usb_cam_node1.cpp and usb_cam_node2.cpp.
I then run them as follows:

> `rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node1 _video_device:=/dev/video1 _camera_name:=cam1` 
> `rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node2 _video_device:=/dev/video2 _camera_name:=cam2`

I added executables to the CMakeList.txt as follows:

> `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node1 nodes/usb_cam_node1.cpp)`
> `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node2 nodes/usb_cam_node2.cpp)`

> `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node1` 
>  `${PROJECT_NAME}` 
> `${avcodec_LIBRARIES}` 
>  `${swscale_LIBRARIES}` 
>  `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` 
> `)`

> `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node2` 
>  `${PROJECT_NAME}` 
> `${avcodec_LIBRARIES}` 
>  `${swscale_LIBRARIES}` 
>  `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` 
> `)`

However every time I execute one after the other, I get the following error.

> [ WARN] [1458914475.903122037]: Shutdown request received. 
> [ WARN] [1458914475.903222764]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]

Quite obviously the nodes are different. Not sure what's going wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230157/running-two-nodes-for-two-webcams-with-usb_cam/) by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What I understood was I need to create two different nodes and set the parameters differently to run them.

yes, but not by copying the source ..

> I then run them as follows:

> ```
> rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node1 _video_device:=/dev/video1 _camera_name:=cam1
> ```

```
rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node2 _video_device:=/dev/video2 _camera_name:=cam2
```

> [..]

> However every time I execute one after the other, I get the following error.

> ```
> [ WARN] [1458914475.903122037]: Shutdown request received.
> ```

```
[ WARN] [1458914475.903222764]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
```

> Quite obviously the nodes are different. Not sure what's going wrong.

No. They're actually not different. It's not the name of the `.cpp` file that needs to be different, it's the *node name*. And that is set in `usb_cam.node.cpp` [here](https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam/blob/6ae47bab49383dd34d4ab7ef01c6056fb93ec0ff/nodes/usb_cam_node.cpp#L271).

Since you didn't change that, ROS detects that you have two nodes with the same name running, and shuts one of them down.

---

But changing the sources to run two instances of the same node is not actually required. You just need to configure them properly. See [Running 2 different cameras using usb_cam](http://answers.ros.org/question/218573) for an example of a launch file that shows how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on 2016-03-25**:
Thank you so much. I'm new to ROS and I missed things which should be obvious.